# Remove words from string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am working on a ASP.NET 4.0 web application, the main goal for it to do is go to the URL in the `MyURL` variable then read it from top to bottom, search for all lines that start with "description" and only keep those while removing all HTML tags. What I want to do next is remove the "description" text from the results afterwords so I have just my device names left. How would I do this?

```
protected void parseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyURL = deviceCombo.Text;
        WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(MyURL);
        objRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        using (StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            originalText.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Read all lines of file
        String[] crString = { "<BR>&nbsp;" };
        String[] aLines = originalText.Text.Split(crString, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        String noHtml = String.Empty;

        for (int x = 0; x < aLines.Length; x++)
        {
            if (aLines[x].Contains(filterCombo.SelectedValue))
            {
                noHtml += (RemoveHTML(aLines[x]) + "\r\n");

            }
        }
        //Print results to textbox
        resultsBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, noHtml);
    }
    public static string RemoveHTML(string text)
    {
        text = text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Replace("<br>", "\n");
        var oRegEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]+>");
        return oRegEx.Replace(text, string.Empty);
    }
```

Comment: I would store the (compiled) Regex in a static variable, that might speed up the process and avoids memory leaks and the \n with Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok so I figured out how to remove the words through one of my existing functions:

```
public static string RemoveHTML(string text)
{
    text = text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Replace("<br>", "\n").Replace("description", "").Replace("INFRA:CORE:", "")
        .Replace("RESERVED", "")
        .Replace(":", "")
        .Replace(";", "")
        .Replace("-0/3/0", "");
        var oRegEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]+>");
        return oRegEx.Replace(text, string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    string str = "He is driving a red car.";

    Console.WriteLine(str.Replace("red", "").Replace("  ", " "));
}
```

Output:
He is driving a car.

Note: In the second Replace its a double space.

Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbluf.png

Try this.It will remove all occurrence of the word which you want to remove.

Comment: what happens with the strings "RED", "Red", "reddit" or "transferred"?

Comment: nothing happens. they are stille "RED", "Red", "reddit"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using LINQ:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>{
"Hello world",
"Description: foo",
"Garbage:baz",
"description purple"};

 //now add all your lines from your html doc.
 if (aLines[x].Contains(filterCombo.SelectedValue))
 {
       lines.Add(RemoveHTML(aLines[x]) + "\r\n");
 }

var myDescriptions = lines.Where(x=>x.ToLower().BeginsWith("description"))
                          .Select(x=> x.ToLower().Replace("description",string.Empty)
                                       .Trim());

// you now have "foo" and "purple", and anything else.
```

You may have to adjust for colons, etc.

Comment: error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToLowerCase' and no extension method 'ToLowerCase' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Also what is the best place to do this since I am using "description" as a filter first.

Comment: @KPS use `ToLower()` not `ToLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    string test = "<html>wowzers description: none <div>description:a1fj391</div></html>";
    IEnumerable<string> results = getDescriptions(test);
    foreach (string result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);  
    }

    //result: none
    //        a1fj391
}

static Regex MyRegex = new Regex(
      "description:\\s*(?<value>[\\d\\w]+)",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

IEnumerable<string> getDescriptions(string html)
{
    foreach(Match match in MyRegex.Matches(html))
    {
        yield return match.Groups["value"].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Adapted From Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/629296/Remove-string-from-match-word-csharp)

```
string value = "ABC - UPDATED";
int index = value.IndexOf(" - UPDATED");
if (index != -1)
{
    value = value.Remove(index);
}
```

It will print `ABC` without `- UPDATED`

Comment: Careful about doing this as Remove will remove all characters from the index to the end of the string. A regex or replace will just do the specific word/chars.